# Can we merge these tags related to Azure SQL managed instance?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

[azure-sql-database-managed-instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-sql-database-managed-instance) having seven questions

[azure-sql-managed-instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-sql-managed-instance) having four questions

Can I go ahead & retag those four questions to the first one? So the second one will vanish automatically. Or does a merge has to happen through a synonym request?

Comment: Why not retag in the other direction? SQL implies a database, so including the database word in the tag seems redundant and lengthy.

Comment: @TylerH that makes sense..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on TylerH comment, I have remapped all the questions from [azure-sql-database-managed-instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-sql-database-managed-instance) to use [azure-sql-managed-instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-sql-managed-instance) tag.